# Href on asp button with Eval

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, eval, href

I'm trying to add a link to my ASP.NET button to redirect the user to another page.

This is the code for a html button that works

```
<a href="RentArticle.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>">Rent article</a>
```

But I want an ASP button that does exactly the same thing.
I've searched around but nothing works.

Here are the "solutions" that I tried

Failed solution #1

```
<a href="RentArticle.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>"><asp:Button ID="btnRentArticle" runat="server" Text="Rent article" CssClass="mybutton" /></a>
```

Result: Browser starts to load but quickly stopt loading and still shows the same page.

Failed solution #2 (Combination with Javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(articleid) { location.href = 'RentArticle.aspx?id=' + articleid; }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnRentArticle" runat="server" onclientclick='redirect(<%#Eval("id")%>)' Text="Rent article" CssClass="mybutton" />
```

Result: same as failed solution #1

Am I doing something wrong or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

#Eval is for databinding expressions, where there's a container and a dataitem. (For example, a row in a Repeater or GridView.) If that's not the case for your button, you need to get the id some other way. For example, declare a hidden field, set the value in the code-behind, and retrieve the value using javascript.

Comment: @Matt, yes. Actually I notice in your first two examples you have nested double quotes, such as `href="RentArticle.aspx?id=<%# Eval("id") %>"` which would not work. Make the outer quotes single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the working example and the last example is that the last one will post back. You can prevent this by adding `return false` to the click handler:

`onclientclick='redirect(<%#Eval("id")%>);return false'`

Comment: That also didn't work. Same result as all the other solutions. I even added a ; to the return false. Same result. Guess I'm gonna use a html button and make a copy of the css

Comment: See what happens if you comment out the line in the javascript function, so it just says `function redirect(articleid) {alert(articleid);}`

Comment: I just copied your Failed solution #2, and it works fine as long as you add the `return false`.